# I Can't Make 1x1 Rects

Tags: python, pygame

I've been wondering this for a while, why can't I make 1x1 rects in Pygame? There are no errors. It doesn't display. If I switch it to 2x2, it displays fine. (And no, it is not my eyesight.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the pygame docs](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), **the area covered by a Rect does not include the right- and bottom-most edge of pixels**. If one Rect’s bottom border is another Rect’s top border (i.e., `rect1.bottom==rect2.top`), the two meet exactly on the screen but do not overlap, and `rect1.colliderect(rect2)` returns `false`. (formatting mine)

In context, this means that, since `rect1.bottom == rect1.top`, `rect1.colliderect(rect1) == false`, so the rect is empty.